# Djagno: Getting objects via ManyToMany "through" model in a single database query

Tags: python, django

Given these models:

```
class Places(models.Model):
    #...

class Tour(models.Model):
    places = ManyToManyField(A, through='TourPlaces')

class TourPlaces(models.Model):
    tour = ForeignKey(Tour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #...
```

How can I build a Queryset so that I can get the Tours a Places belongs to on the SQL side without hitting the database repeatedly? Pseudo example:

```
for place in Places.objects.(some kind of annotation maybe?):
    print(place.tours[0])
```

Instead of

```
for place in Places.objects.all():
    print(TourPlaces.objects.get(place=place).tour[0])
```

Context: My REST Framework ModelSerializer for Places, using the code above in a SerializerMethodField, is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Places(models.Model):
    first_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    second_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Tour(models.Model):
    places = ManyToManyField(A, through='TourPlaces')

class TourPlaces(models.Model):
    tour = ForeignKey(Tour, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    place = ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then :

```
TourPlaces.objects.filter(place__first_field = 'some')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this and improved performance a lot by using prefetch_related with the reverse set:

```
for place in Places.objects.prefetch_related('tour_set').all():
    print(str(place.tour_set.first()))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

My REST view set and model serializer look like this now:

```
class PlaceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (JSONParser,)
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
    queryset = Place.objects.prefetch_related('tour_set')

class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tour = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_tour')

    def _tour(self, obj):
        try:
            return str(obj.tour_set.first())
        except:
            return ""

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = (
            '...',
            'tour',
        )
```